# how to configure a custom sales_quote_totals

Tags: xml, magento, quote

I don´t understand the tags that configure a custom sales quote. In this code snippet:

```
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <custom>
                    <class>custom/quote_address_total_custom</class>
                    <before>grand_total,....</before>
                    <after>subtotal,shipping,...</after>
                    <render>....</render>
                </custom>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

I want to know what are the posibles values for before,after and render tags and the consecuence to check a custom parameter. 
In the example you can see

```
<before>grand_total,....</before>
```

Does this mean that my custom quote render later the gran_total are calculate???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the possible values that you can use in the `before` and `after` tags are the other tags *composing* the quote, ie: subtotal, grand_total, tax, shipping, etc... In clear, the distincts totals of the quotes.
And regarding your question:

> ```
> <before>grand_total,....</before>
> ```
>
> Does this mean that my custom quote render later the gran_total are calculate???

no, just the other way around: there you are saying **before** the `grand_total` total.

About the `<render>` tag, I don't think it is valid in this scope... or maybe it is, I dunno. Anyway, in it you put the block class definition you want it to use, for example:

```
<render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_text</render>
```

means it uses `the Mage_Core_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Text` class

Comment: where can i find the tags composing the quote, in the config.xml of Mage_Sales module?? thanks osDave

Comment: @davidselo yep, there, inside the global - sales - quote - totals tag. yw